# Usando corretamente o wpdb->insert na função

Tags: sql, wordpress

Estou tentando inserir os dados do formulario criado pelo pluguin Contact Form 7 para minha tabela 'wp_wpdatatable_2', criei um hook usando add_action e tudo certo, porem não envia ao banco e eu não recebo a mensagem de sucesso(loop infinito ao tentar enviar), algum conselho?

Editado:

```
function wpcf7_do_something ($WPCF7_ContactForm) {
    global $wpdb;
    WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();   
    $numbene = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["NumerodoContrato"];
    $especie = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["Especie"];
    $descontm = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["DescontoMensal"];
    $nome = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["nome"];
    $file645 = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["file-645"];
    $file646 = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["file-646"];
    $file647 = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data["file-647"];


    $wpdb->insert ('wp_wpdatatable_2', array(
        'NumerodoContrato' => $numbene,
        'especie' => $especie,
        'descontomensal' => $descontm,
        'nome' => $nome,
        'anexoidentidade' => $file645,
        'anexocomprovanteresidencia' => $file646,
        'anexodocumentoextra' => $file647


    ) );  


    }
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something", 10, 1);
```

Comment: Já tentou `add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something", 10, 1);` ? O `action` está acessando a função? O nome dos campos estão corretos?

Comment: Acabei de tentar, mesma coisa, os campos estão. E sim, usei  um pluguin customizado seguindo este tutorial https://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/

Comment: Já tentou substituir a variável `$cf7` por `$WPCF7_ContactForm`? Ou ainda `$cf7 = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();` antes de usa-la? Sem esquecer `global $wpdb;` na primeira linha da função

Comment: Vou atualizar o código para ficar mais claro o que ja fiz. e sim adicionei a variavel global.

Comment: Mesmo erro ainda, chequei para ver se estava certo as variaveis do formulario e estão certos, parece algum erro na execução do sql, porque se fosse o hook, não estaria nem dando o loop ou daria erro 500